# why the following code not printing the common unique values from the two files

Tags: perl

I have two files. I am trying to find out all common numbers from the two files without repetition. Following are the details of two files

myresult

```
0..351
12..363
24..375
36..387
48..399
```

annotation

```
272..1042
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open( $inp0, "<myresult" )   or die "not found";
open( $inp2, "<annotation" ) or die "not found";
open( $out,  ">output" );
my @arr2 = <$inp0>;
my @arr4 = <$inp2>;
my $from = ( split /\.\./, $arr2[0] )[0];
my $to   = ( split /\.\./, $arr2[-1] )[1];

for my $i ( $from .. $to ) {
    print $out "$i\n" if grep inside( $i, $_ ), @arr2 and grep inside( $i, $_ ), @arr4;
}

sub inside {
    my ( $i, $range ) = @_;
    my ( $from, $to ) = split /\.\./, $range;
    return ( $from <= $i and $i <= $to );
}
```

output should be: numbers from 272 to 399. but this code is just giving 0.

Comment: Works for me. I get 272..399.

Comment: What did you do to [my code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26382937/1030675)?